# Characterization of open sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, axiom-of-choice

I have a question concerning the characterization of open sets in a metric space.

Per definition a set O in a metric space (X,d) is open, if it is a neighborhood of each of its points. 
In the book "Introduction to Topology" by Mendelson (https://archive.org/details/IntroductionToTopology/page/n33/mode/2up) there  is the following characterization:

Theorem (5.2): 
A subset O of a metric space (X,d) is an open set if and only if it is the union of open balls.

The proof of one direction is as follows:
Suppose O is open. Then for each $a \in O$, there is an open ball $B(a;\delta_a) \subset O$. Therefore $O = \bigcup_{a \in O} B(a;\delta_a)$ is a union of open balls.

Now I wonder: Does this argument require the **axiom of choice**?

You need a 'choice function' which assigns to each $a \in O$, an element $\delta_a$ from the (non empty) set of all $\delta$'s where $B(a;\delta) \subset O$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't require the axiom of choice. You can, for each $a\in O$, take the smallest $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $B\left(a;\frac1n\right)\subset O$.

Comment: Or not choose at all and simply consider *all* open balls centered at each point and contained in $O$.

Comment: Thanks, that convincing